# lightning:recordEditForm error. Field does not exist

Tags: lightning-aura-components, error, fields, error-messages, lightning-recordeditform

When using `lightning:recordEditForm` I am getting the following error in the 
`<lightning:messages />`:

> Field does not exist.

Here is the markup I am using:

```
<lightning:recordEditForm aura:id="trainingRecordEditForm"
                                              recordId="{!v.currentlySelectedId}"
                                              objectApiName="{!v.objectApiName}"
                                              onsuccess="{!c.handleSuccess}" onerror="{!c.handleError}">
                        <lightning:messages />

                        <aura:iteration items="{!v.fields}" var="field">
                            <lightning:inputField fieldName="{!field}" />
                        </aura:iteration>

                        <lightning:inputField class="hiddenField"
                                              fieldName="{!v.fieldWithParentId}"
                                              value="{!v.currentlySelectedId}"/>

                    </lightning:recordEditForm>
```

Nothing special, really.

Here is the params of the error event:
`"{"error":{"message":"Field  does not exist.","stackTrace":"","data":{"message":"Field  does not exist.","statusCode":400,"errorCode":"POST_BODY_PARSE_ERROR"},"id":"1408552758"}}"`

What I am doing more precisely:

1. I open the component successfully.
2. Change nothing in the fields.
3. Click button which submits the `<lightning:recordEditForm>`.

[image]

Comment: If your fields are not generated with an aura iteration does it work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here `<lightning:inputField class="hiddenField" fieldName="{!v.fieldWithParentId}" value="{!v.currentlySelectedId}"/>` I had **v.fieldWithParentId** being equal to an empty string.